# Copy duplicate and unique rows to Different Excel Sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I get a daily log of data for which I want to run a VBA code to compare data in sheet 1 and sheet 2 and then copy common rows to another sheet, and unique rows to another sheet.

**Issue #1:** I am unable to successfully do this for 100,000 plus rows as excel crashes.

**Issue #2:** I am unsure how to create a sheet for unique rows where there is no match.

**Issue #3:** Does no always copy duplicates.

Could someone help me make changes to this code to help meet it's functionality.

```
Sub Duplicate_Rows()
 Dim ur1 As Range, ur2 As Range, dupeRows As Range
    Dim r1 As Range, s1 As String, r2 As Range, s2 As String

    Set ur1 = Worksheets("qry").UsedRange.Rows
    Set ur2 = Worksheets("Dump").UsedRange.Rows  'Find duplicates from Sheet1 in Sheet2

    Set dupeRows = ur2(Worksheets("Dump").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
    For Each r1 In ur1
        s1 = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(r1)))
        For Each r2 In ur2
            s2 = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(r2)))
            If s1 = s2 Then
                If Intersect(dupeRows, r2) Is Nothing Then
                    Set dupeRows = Union(dupeRows, r2)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Dim wb As Workbook, wsDupes As Worksheet    'Move duplicate rows to new Sheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsDupes = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
    wsDupes.Name = "Dump Duplicates - " & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd-hhmmss")
    dupeRows.Copy
    With wsDupes.Cells(1)
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        .Select
    End With
    dupeRows.EntireRow.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What line returns the error message?

Comment: Set dupeRows = ur2(Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)

This line gives an issue after debugging. And I do not know how to create a new sheet for unique rows

Comment: What are you attempting to do with that line?

Comment: I essentially receive data daily where I am required to see which data is identical, and which data is unique or rather doesn't match. Sheet 1 contains the data where sheet 2 is being compared to. I want to create a code which puts duplicate rows into a sheet, and unique rows into another sheet

Comment: Looks like you fixed your `Subscript out of range` error by using the correct sheetname.  But now your question does not seem to have question. Please edit it to indicate what your problem is now.  Also, what does the `macos` tag have to do with your problem?

Comment: It seems I put the macos instead of macros. But The question has now been added back in.

Comment: If you read the description for the `macros` tag, it seems it should not be being used for Office/VBA.

Comment: Especially with so large a data set, I suggest you change your method of finding duplicates by reading your data into a 2D VBA array (one single line of code `myArray = myRange`, then use two dictionary objects to detect the duplicates and split up the rows the way you want.  Then write the results back to the relevant worksheets.

Comment: Hey Ron, thanks for the suggestion. I actually do not know how to do this as I just started using vba just for this task to be completed. Could you possibly show me how this can be achieved, please!